# Outlet and lights not working

Tags: receptacle, circuit-breaker, gfci, light

Wanted to post this here to see if I could get any tips or things I’ve missed

I have a Lennar built home in 2019.

A few days ago my wife was using a hair dryer in mater bedroom and all of a sudden outlet lost power. Upon reviewing further:

-all the outlets in master bedrooms don’t work
-the light switches in master bedroom don’t work
-two outlets in the “network hub” that Lennar install in the laundry room don’t work (all other outlets in laundry room work).
-laundry room is right beside master bedroom
-everything in master bath (connected to master bedroom) is working
-all other outlets are working

Electrician came and did the following:
-Check all outlets. Said non were getting power and no loose connection
-said the breaker had power
-said could be burnt wires and will need to cut through drywall to figure out

I’ve done:
-endlessly check for GFCI outlets and non triggered
-breakers that were labeled “gfi” weren’t triggered either. But I turned them off and on again.

Electrician will come after Christmas to dig deeper. But while I wait I figured I’d post here to see if anyone had any ideas.

I find it kinda weird that everything in master bedroom stopped working and then the outlets in the network hub in laundry are the only other outlets not working.

Anyone have any other suggestions to look at? Maybe someone has dealt with Lennar homes and know something that we are missing?

Thanks for reading and helping!

Comment: Usually bathrooms/kitchens are suppose to be by themselves, not connected to other rooms.  If electrician checked all the outlets/lights/switches/boxes for bad connections, inside walls is quite possible(mice).  Back stab push in(cheap and fast to use) connections are a known trouble connection, so screw only connection is recommended and should be changed before ripping walls open.

Comment: Thank you. I have time today so I am thinking about opening outlets and checking for loose connections. This might sound like a dumb question, but I should open up working outlets and lights to see if there’s loose connection, correct? 
He didn’t open up actual lights we have, like in ceiling lights for loose connections. 

Any specific tools I should purchase to help with this? 

Thanks.

Comment: Turn off the breaker/s and check for power before opening up.  The problem is usually at the last working device in line or the first non working device.  One circuit can have a few devices(outlets/lights).  Both the black and white(120 volt) wires must have good connection to work.  Ground/bare is nice for your safety/protection but does not matter for a circuit to work if not connected.  A multi-meter is nice, and newer code requires a torque screwdriver for connections, both not too expensive(20 bucks each).  A non contact voltage detector is much nicer than checking with your fingers .

Comment: I really hope the electrician's strategy isn't to go straight to cutting drywall before checking every receptacle. If it is, you need a better electrician. Start with the receptacle the dryer was plugged into. Go toward the panel (I know, that's imprecise) and look at receptacles that are working. Try and map which functioning receptacle is on which breaker.

Comment: It would be nice to know if all non-working outlets are on a single breaker, and also if any still-working outlets are on the same breaker.

Comment: It does look like all non working outlets and light switch is on a single breaker. I’m not sure if the network hub outlets are in the same breaker or not. 

I got a voltage tester and outlet tester. Outlet tester shows no light when plugged into outlets. Voltage tester shows no power when I try to touch the wires in the light switch box. 

Breaker was replaced and shows it has power. But nothing is coming into the room. 

Some pics of the light switch box where wires are coming in. 
https://ibb.co/X4x4sbY
https://ibb.co/GxTSfSt
https://ibb.co/qNQHC1M

Comment: So if the outlet tester shows no lights, then should I still be looking at the outlets that are working closest to the non working outlet to see if something is lose?

Comment: To add to this. I turned off the master room breaker to take pics.

I just realized that our walk in closet light in master bed is connected to the same breaker as all outlets since now that is not working either (since breaker is off).

So is it safe to assume that power from breaker is getting up to the closet since light is working? Maybe I should take that apart and see if anything is lose there?

Comment: It will not hurt(if the power is off) to check.  Most of this type of work is undoing and checking till you find the problem/s.

Comment: So I was able to fix the electrical issue! 

We realized that the walk in closet in master bedroom was connected to the same breaker as all the outlets and lights in master bedroom. 
Since the walk in closet light was working, I opened that switch. Just make sure everything was pushed in and tightened and when I turned on the breaker, everything worked! 

It is crazy that two electrician didn’t catch this. Paid them both more than $400 to do nothing.

Comment: Where is this - - country, state, city?

Comment: How was the switch to the walkin closet wired--was it pushed into holes in the back?

Comment: Yes backstabbed. Terrible wiring but I guess it’s expected from these cookie cutter homes